# Simple example of C# Flash Callback

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to write a simple command-line C# program that calls a function in a compiled Flash ActionScript 3.0 and then displays the string output. There is already a callback function registered in the SWF file I can make use of.

After some research ([mainly following the example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12010/Fun-with-C-and-the-Flash-Player-External-API)), this is what I have so far:

```
using AxShockwaveFlashObjects;
using System;

namespace ConsoleProg {
    class ConsoleProg {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            string path = "container.swf";
            AxShockwaveFlash flash = new AxShockwaveFlash();
            flash.LoadMovie(0, path);
            string result = flash.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"api_function\" returntype=\"xml\"><arguments></arguments></invoke>");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

(The callbacked function in the SWF file takes no arguments and returns a short string.)

Compiling and running this gives the error that the
`ActiveX control cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.`

So I looked around and tried two things: I added `[STAThread]` to the `Main` method. Now it gives the error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException: E
xception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was
thrown.
```

The other thing I did was to spin off the console program into an object and instantiate it in its own thread, specifying its apartment state explicitly:

```
using AxShockwaveFlashObjects;
using System.Threading;
using System;

namespace ConsoleProg {
    class ConsoleProg {
        public string path;

        public ConsoleProg (string path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public void LoadFlash() {
            AxShockwaveFlash flash = new AxShockwaveFlash();
            flash.LoadMovie(0, this.path);
            string result = flash.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"api_function\" returntype=\"xml\"><arguments></arguments></invoke>");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        static void Main (string[] args) {
            ConsoleProg cp = new ConsoleProg("api_container.swf");

            Thread t = new Thread(cp.LoadFlash);
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the same error as my other try above.

At this point I'm at a loss. What am I doing wrong? It would help greatly if someone can point to me a simple but complete example, because all the tutorials I see online come in code fragments that I'm unable to assemble into something that works.

All I need the program to do, is to print in the console the string that the flash file outputs. This is supposed to be part of a larger program, but right now I just want to get a simple example working.

Comment: I am not sure if swf can be used as util console program. Basically, it will work only in Flash player. You cannot just start swf file as is (like you do with console app) and wait for something from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my projects does that so I'm going to share some code snippets with you to give you a hand.
First of all make sure your project build target is x86. I couldn't get x64 or AnyCpu to work at all.
Who knows, this may fix all your issues.

If not, try using this code I borrowed from my project to perform the function call:

```
public string InvokeFlashFunction(string functionName, params object[] functionParameters)
{
    //Creates the xml that will be sent to the flash movie
    XmlDocument invokeDocument = new XmlDocument();
    //Creates the invoke element that will be the root element of the xml
    XmlElement rootElement = invokeDocument.CreateElement("invoke");
    //Set both attributes of the invoke element
    rootElement.SetAttribute("name", functionName);
    rootElement.SetAttribute("returnType", "xml");
    //Creates the arguments element
    XmlElement childNode = invokeDocument.CreateElement("arguments");
    //foreach parameter, creates a child node to the arguments element
    foreach (object param in functionParameters)
    {
        XmlElement paramNode = GetParamXml(param, invokeDocument);
        //appends the parameters
        childNode.AppendChild(paramNode);
    }
    //Appends the arguments node
    rootElement.AppendChild(childNode);
    //Call the function
    return _FlashMovie.CallFunction(rootElement.OuterXml);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
InvokeFlashFunction("api_function", "your arguments here");
```